# How to pass ITestNGMethod in @AfterClass method as parameter?

Tags: testng

I was trying to know that after which @Test(test method), @AfterClass got invoked. So to know that I wrote following code to do that:

```
@AfterClass(alwaysRun = true)
  public synchronized void tearDownClass(final ITestNGMethod itx) {

  final Method m = itx.getConstructorOrMethod().getMethod();

  System.out.println(m.getName());

}
```

But testNG throws following error:
**Method tearDownClass requires 1 parameters but 0 were supplied in the @Configuration annotation.**

So my question is how to resolve above issue, or is there any other way to achieve this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This wouldn't make sense: it's an `@AfterClass` method, which gets invoked after all the test methods of the class have run. Your specific scenario (wanting to know the last method invoked) is very specific so you should implement it yourself.

For example, you could create a field `lastMethod` and have each method set it with its name so that when you reach the `@AfterClass`, you know which one ran last.

Comment: Implemented as directed, and it worked like a charm. Thanks @Cedric.

Comment: You got me ! That's exactly what I will propose !

Answer (score 0):

It can't work because `ITestNGMethod` represents a method and a class can have many methods.

You can inject `ITestContext` instead and look for your methods into it.

Comment: So if I use ITestContext, it gives all the '@Test methods'. But didn't found any method which can provide details like after which @Test method, current '@AfterClass' method got executed. Please let me know if my question is not clear so that I can provide sample code for explanation.

Comment: If I understand well, you want the last executed method of the class ?